# Changed sub-site to its own domain trigger 302 redirects for all page links

Tags: multisite, permalinks, domain-mapping

Below, I'm calling the development site `mainsite.com` (containing the WPMS install) and the domain that will point to a Norwegian sub-site of `mainsite.com`, I call `launchsite.no`.

A **Norwegian sub-site** is ready to be launched, and the client is ready to point `launchsite.no` to the Wordpress installation. I'm manually pointing `launchsite.no` to the correct IP address in HOSTS to make sure it's ready for the 'switch'.

So it's not a migration question. The host has internally made an alias for `launchsite.no` to be the same directory where the WPMS install is.

- The site works perfectly when Domain is set to `mainsite.com` and Path is set to `/no/` (in wp-admin).
- Just pointing `launchsite.no` to the server IP gives me `mainsite.com` (main site, not Norwegian). (And `launchsite.no/wp-admin` doesn't work.)
- I changed the Domain to `launchsite.no` and the Path to `/` for the Norwegian site.
- This gives me `launchsite.no` (yay!) and if I hover on all links on the site, they are correct, like launchsite.com/om-oss (About Us page). But when I click them, all of them give 302 Moved Temporarily and I end up on `mainsite.com`!

I'm having trouble debugging this. I have read [these documents](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Multisite) and [these](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_URL_directly_in_the_database) from the codex

The Site URL and Home in the database are correct, and there are no relevant occurrences of `mainsite.com/no/`.

I've tested out some URLs that work and some that don't, hoping that it will give a clue.

- `launchsite.no/wp-admin/` - OK (phew!)
- `launchsite.no/` - OK, Norwegian start page.
- `launchsite.no/om-oss` (page) - 302 redirect to `mainsite.com`!
- `launchsite.no/?pagename=om-oss` (same page) - OK!
- `launchsite.no/?page_id=18` (same page) - 302 redirect to `mainsite.com`.

I have disabled the Rewrite and Yoast SEO plugins (since they are capable of doing 301 redirects), no difference.

I have saved and flushed Wordpress' rewrite rules.

The host will not help me with Wordpress, but just says WP Multisite works on their servers. So I would be very grateful for suggestions what causes this, where I should look.

### It seems that Wordpress' own permalink translation is broken after the "sub-site move".

**UPDATE:**

### I think I've ruled out everything but an error in wp_rewrite. Is there a way to catch or log what Wordpress is rewriting the page Permalinks to? Is there a third value apart from siteroot and home that it uses, that I could check in the database?

Here is my .htaccess (standard, from the multisite article on wordpress.com):

```
Options All -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

#make sure in development site is not found by search engines.
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

And here's my wp-config:

```
$table_prefix = 'wp_';

/**
* WordPress Localized Language, defaults to English.
*
* Change this to localize WordPress. A corresponding MO file for the chosen
* language must be installed to wp-content/languages. For example, install
* de_DE.mo to wp-content/languages and set WPLANG to 'de_DE' to enable German
* language support.
*/
define('WPLANG', '');

/**
* For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
*
* Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
* It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
* in their development environments.
*/
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mainsite.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', true);
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `wp-config.php` indicates that you've set up a **subdirectory** installation, but you want to be able to use different **domain names** for the sites. To do that, I believe you'll need a plugin of some sort.

A quick search indicates that [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) *may* do what you need. Be sure to read [the installation instructions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/installation/) carefully -- it looks somewhat more involved than the usual "put the plugin in `wp-content/plugins` and activate".

*Caveat:* I have a fair amount of experience in WordPress Multisite subdirectory installations, but my WPMS subdomain knowledge is pretty thin. If I've made an error, please correct me.

Comment: Yes, I did this a day before your answer. This was *the* solution. I just kept the subfolder mapping and the plugin mapped up the domains beautifully, and even let me set priority for www/no www. I did look at this before that actually, but the WPMU in title and description turned me away.

Perfect plugin, easy to install and use.